# How to handle delete of entity and post delete-operation to a REST sink in SESAM

Tags: rest, sesam

What is the best practice to handle delete operations for REST sink in SESAM? The case is that I have an incoming entity "Vendor" that gets posted with post-operation to the rest sink this creates the vendor in BigQuery, then the vendor get deleted from the source dataset. The entity Vendor with _id=1 will have the _deleted=true. What is the best way to trigger the delete-vendor operation?

System config:
"operations": {
"delete-vendor": {
"method": "DELETE",
"rate_limiting_delay": 60,
"rate_limiting_retries": 3,
"url": "rest/vendor/{{_id}}"
},
"post-vendor": {
"method": "POST",
"payload-type": "json",
"url": "rest/vendor"
},

BR

Truong

I've tried the following config but realize it's not going to work:

{
"_id": "vendor-rest",
"type": "pipe",
"source": {
"type": "dataset",
"dataset": "global-vendor"
},
"transform": {
"type": "dtl",
"rules": {
"default": [
["if",
["eq", "_S._deleted", true],
["add", "operation", "delete-vendor"],
["add", "operation", "post-vendor"]
],
["add", "payload",
["apply", "payload", "_S."]
]
],
"payload": [
["copy", "*",
["list", "_id", "_deleted", "_ts", "_updated", "_previous", "_hash"]
]
]
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer for your question, it could be a solution to instead use the bigquery microservice from Sesam Community.

https://github.com/sesam-community/google-bigquery-sink

Comment: Nice, thanks for the reply. I'll check it out

Comment: The parsing of google_application_credentials is failing in version 1.5.1 of the google-bigquery-sink ms.  2024-02-09T12:16:43.780062001Z   File "bq_sink.py", line 1329, in <module>
2024-02-09T12:16:43.780066701Z     client = bigquery.Client()
2024-02-09T12:16:43.780071001Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 231, in __init__
2024-02-09T12:16:43.780151003Z     credential_type = info.get("type")
2024-02-09T12:16:43.780154103Z AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: doesn't seem to correct written to temp-file, the readback is failing